# I need to figure out how to buy a used server. What is the thing called that pulls out from a stack server an has a screen on it an keyboard?

Tags: networking, cisco, laptop, display

I want to buy the computer that technicians use to repair or configure stack servers it looks just like a laptop but has hot swappable harddrives. I'm entering a i.t. program an I'd like to mess with building my own server while I do my schooling. Can anybody tell me what the hell that thing is called? It has a screen an keyboard an mouse pad I've searched the net for days an none of the pictures I've seen have the screen or keyboard they just keep showing me a flat box. Plz help

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are talking about a "Rackmount KVM"

https://www.google.com/search?q=rackmount+kvm

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rackmount_KVM

But this does not have hard drives because it is not a full system. It only has monitor / keyboard / mouse which are connected via cables to the servers in the same rack